# How to calculate ratio via akka-stream

Tags: java, scala, akka-stream

Looking how ratio (percentage) can be calculated  per each element in a stream.

`(10,20,30,40,50)->(10/150, 20/150, 30/150, 40/150, 50/150)` **150** is reduced sum of elements in a stream

Graph should reduce stream to one element and then apply that one element to each element in a stream

I was thinking about broadcast(2) stream, then in (1) make a reduce (calculate sum), (2) should be the same, and then zip it somehow. Problem that zip is 1:1 combining.

Comment: What would happen if, after emitting `10/150, 20/150, ..., 50/150`, a `60` came down the pike?  Would you expect only a `60/210` to be emitted or would you be expecting a `10/210`, `20/210` etc. to be emitted?

Comment: Are you sure that stream is the right approach? Sounds like your data is finite, and then maybe finite data structures may be more suitable.

Comment: The data is finite. 95% is simple mappings/ calculations that's why I'm looking on a streams. We have a record with Id, for every item I need to calculate something, it could be a chain of calculations and then group calculation result to some entity.

Comment: Example: input record (id:1, data:"text", cost:100) expected output (id:1, length:4, more_then_limit:true). Calculations can be done in parallel. In one case we have aggregation, which is not fit to streaming processing. That's why I'm looking is it possible to do it

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding to the question an example input, example output, and what is the logic to get the output.

Comment: Not sure why if data is finite you want to use `Streams`? Maybe you are confused with **Java** `Streams` which are just basically anything but a real stream.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the data is finite (implication: the upstream source will complete), something like this (in Scala) will work.

```
def normalizeToTotal(source: Source[Int, Any]): Source[Double, NotUsed] =
  source.map(i => Option(i))  // map everything to Some...
    .concat(Source.single(None)) // so we can use None to signal upstream completion
    .statefulMapConcat { () =>
      var elems: List[Int] = Nil
      { elem: Option[Int] =>
        elem.foreach { e => elems = e :: elems }  // only when not yet completed
        if (elem.isEmpty) {
          // upstream is completing (None is the last element)
          val des = elems.map(_.toDouble)
          val sum = des.sum
          val toEmit = des.reverse.map(_ / sum)
          elems = Nil  // preserve our invariant even in death...
          toEmit
        } else {
          // not yet completed, don't emit
          Nil
        }
      }
    }
```

Disclaimer: the compiler in my mind passes this.

It needs to be noted that this will consume memory proportional to the number of elements in the stream (due to the requirement to not emit until all elements are known): this is not a streaming algorithm, but a batch algorithm implemented to a streaming API.

(then again, if a stream can be viewed as a stream of small batches (I see you, Spark...), batch processing can equally be viewed as a stream that's most often "dry")

It can also be noted that the `statefulMapConcat` stage (as long as it maintains its invariant) will work with an infinite stream of `Option[Int]`s, interpreting `None` as an emit-at-end-of-batch indicator.  It may still be useful to `concat(Source.single(None))` on its input to ensure batch termination if modifying it to consume such a stream, of course.